# Save only a subset of the referenced hibernate collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate as ORM in my Java application. I have an entity 
Parent that has a one-to-many relationship to some Child class and cascade type set to 'ALL'. Also in the Child class I've referenced the Parent class with a many-to-one annotation. 
In the child class I have some methods that decides if the object should be persisted or not. I do this in an PreInsertEventListener that I've added to the sessionfactory registry.
All goes well in the logs I see only the subset of inserts but when the transaction gets commited I get the error that not all references are saved.

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing.

TLDR:
UI sends me many children object in the parent but I want to save only some of them. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you marked any field transient in the child entity? Please share the parent and child entity.

Comment: Transient means not persistent. You can't/shouldn't do this. Change the parent not to use cascade type ALL if you want other code to decide if the child objects should be saved or not. Work with Hibernate - not against it.